# Fetching and display the data in a Django Template Using MYSQL RAW SQL QUERY

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here is my Django Template Used to Display The data in table Format...

`enter code here`

```
<table class="content" border="2px">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>S-No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Productname</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Ordertime</th>
    <th>Orderstatus</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in records %}
  <tr align="center">    
    <td>{{row.pid}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.productname }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.ordertime }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.orderstatus }}</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Accept">  <input type="button" value="Reject"></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody> 
</table>
```

And This is my Views.py Page for the fetching up of the data

```
 def viewpro(request):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='company1')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_order")
    records=cur.fetchall()
    print(records)
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    #context = {'viewpro' : user_order.objects.all()}
    return render(request, "viewpro.html", {'records':records})
```

But Here The problem is it display the no.of table rows same like DB(It have 4 records and table shows 4 rows But no data in the fields).....Pls Help me to get rid of that....Only using raw queries....

Comment: May be your context data format is not as per rendering it to template. Check your query response, if object has been creating then code is working perfectly but your table data in <td> may be unable to find the data you mentioned.Make it proper format like a object or a json.

Comment: @skhynixsk But it shows the data in cmd by using print(records)..i am unable to send those data to the template...The output data in cmd is [(1, 'chakrapani', 'chakri@gmail.com', 'dark', '9', '10', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 22, 14, 26, 8), 'Pending.....'), (2, 'chakrapani', 'chakri@gmail.com', '5star', '5', '5', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 22, 14, 29, 32), 'Pending.....'), (3, 'chakrapani', 'chakri@gmail.com', 'dairymilk', '3', '100', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 24, 14, 23, 58), 'Pending.....')]

Comment: It is not in key,value pair manner if you fetch data then how could you get it . <td>{{row..pid}}</td>
    <td>{{ row.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.productname }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.quantity }}</td>

Comment: Make a proper fomat of that data to a json format or use django query for retriving the data if  you are using django.

Comment: @skhynixsk That .pid,.username,.email like these names are the columns names in my DB... If it wrong then please correct me,because it is more helpful for my career and also this is my first django project try to do..Thank you

Comment: <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
<td>{{ row[1] }}</td>


Use accordingly using index.Ok it will work for temp purpose.

Comment: @skhynixsk it works bro but it takes list instead of using dictionaries...so i am used <td>{{row.0}}</td>,<td>{{row.1}}</td> manner,but any suggestion to get data instead of using that row.0 type....Thank u for ur concern

Comment: please dump your db query results to json. Then it will be helpful.